# How to get guid from unknown com object interface (e.g. connection point)?

Tags: c#, com, interface, guid, connection-points

I've got running service which is available via COM. I can connect with it by using `Activator`.

I connect COM library

```
using MyLib;
```

and then get my object by Instance

```
Activator.CreateInstance((Type.GetTypeFromProgID("RunningInstance")));
```

this is actually `IConnectionPointContainer`

there are several connection points and to get one there is

```
FindConnectionPoint(SomeGuidHere, out MyConnectionPoint);
```

if I remember correctly in cpp atl there is just `__uuid(IHelloWorld)`

the problem is: how to get guide of some "IHelloWorld" interface (connection point) in the Container ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EnumConnectionPoints()` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/670585).

Comment: so... is it a joke? I don't see.

Comment: @ℋeatђer: Not a joke, just the link was not properly formatted. Fixed it.

Comment: I see but sadly in example he's getting full list of points and it's some overhead comparing to way when I use an static uuid. But yet I can't find better solution I mark this one as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the interface, you can get the GUID from the type.

```
typeof(IHelloWorld).GUID
```

Comment: That doesn't require a reference to the COM interface, just knowing the type name of the wrapper type. If you had a reference to the actual instance you'd need to use GetType(). And if it's a simple object reference you'll be disappointed at the results of it. I'm still trying to figure out if there's any way to find the GUID of a __ComObject (the internal type the runtime holds it in) when all you have is an IUnknown as a System.Object ... really looks like there's no legit way to do it ...